# Ubuntu 22.10 drop to initramfs on fresh install with full disk encryption

Tags: boot, luks, initramfs

I have been trying to reinstall Ubuntu 22.10 with full disk encryption using the default install options, but I keep running into the same issue where after finishing the install, the splash screen on reboot hangs with a message of waiting for the encrypted volume, then it fails and drops me into an initramfs terminal. Using instructions 1-6 listed in response #5 on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1979159 , I was able to decrypt the drive and Ubuntu boots normally on exit from initramfs, but I have been unable to restart without following these instructions manually each time. I was lucky to stumble on these instructions while facing this issue when i first updated from an older version to 22.04, but I've now wiped the drive multiple times trying to move to a fresh install of 22.10.

I'm unsure of how to proceed as most other suggested fixes revolve around getting back into the decrypted drive and running "sudo update-grub" or "update-initramfs -u", but these have all returned successfully (as best as I can tell). Update-initramfs exits with a messsage that it will attempt to resume from "/dev/dm-7" which is the encrypted drive, and /etc/crypttab points to the correct UUID.

Any advice or way to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have /dev/mapper/isw... as described in that comment? are you using dmraid?